# Кодировка и JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Снова столкнулся с траблой - 100%, что элементрарщина какая-то, но не могу сдвинуться дальше.
Получаю я GET-ом строку из JSON-а:

```
public static class Get {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void run(String url, Callback callback) {
        okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
}
```

В логкате прилетает такое:

```
"89435": {
    "Amount": "0",
    "Keep": "",
    "Name": "\u041f\u0438\u0432\u043e \u041f\u0448\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0447\u043d\u043e\u0435 \u0412\u0438\u0442\u0411\u0438\u0440 0,33",
    "Sum": "0",
    "Unit": "\u041f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u044f"
},
```

Если юзать браузерный сервис для отправки хттп запросов, то получаем странность:
в разделе Content данные в том же виде, что и у меня в логкате:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а в разделе JSON проблем с кодировкой нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Игрался с хидерами: .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8") - разные варианты запихивал сюда, не помогло.

Делать как в POST-е:

```
MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, ***********);
```

но в доке по GET-у не нашел я как это прикрутить т.к. это только для пост-запросов актуально (если я правильно понял), да и я уже указываю ему явно кодировку в хидере...

Что я делаю не так? Как получить доступ к данным для дальнейшего парсинга?
Спасибо!

Comment: а если без кодировки попробовать отправить? то есть только пробрасывать что вы отправляете json?

Comment: Всё правильно прилетает, кодировка здесь абсолютно ни при чём, просто надо json распарсить любым подручным парсером

Comment: Andrew, без кодировки тот же эффект.

andreymal, можете ткнуть где почитать или на похожий пример?

Comment: _можете ткнуть где почитать_ : [как парсить json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+json) . Вы же не будете разбирать ответ вручную сабстрингами или регулярками надеюсь... Вот если после парсинга json-библиотекой у вас будет неправильный текст - тогда это проблема и с ней надо разбираться.